# Application validity if installed from XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I have installed my app from XCode into my iPhone by development certificate. Just want to know how many days it will be valid in my device ?

Note, I will not likely to uninstall it from device or i will not do anything forcefully just to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application will be valid **till you want to use even if the certificates are expired**. But, as soon as you uninstall the app from your device, you need to regenerate the certificates. **None of the application affect with the expiration of the certificates**.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will not work if its build with Development provisioning profile and Profile has expired. SO expiration period of your app depends on remaining day for your provision profile expiration- which you can check from  developer.apple.com

However , If app is installed from App Store and there is no expiry date. even if your provision profile gets expired app will work if its installed through app store.